# Shopping Cart Value

Tags: e-commerce

I'm looking for a method to calculate the value of a cart, this could be for a user who is logged in (though perhaps not). What is the best method JavaScript (or can it be done in Firebase). To get an idea of value. It seems rather complex so I'm looking for a consensus of ideas (if you can spare the time).

Comment: A shopping cart? Would it not just be the sum of the prices?

Comment: what happens if users add/remove items...